# How to send push Notification using FCM and Flutter(One to Another Device)?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have devloped One to one chat system in flutter and want to send push notification to another device using FCM.

I have setup all the flutter and firebase messaging requirement.

```
//In InitState()
_firebaseMessaging.onTokenRefresh.listen(sendTokenToServer);
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
      print("onLaunch");
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Message(this.user, this.event)),
      );
    }, onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
      print("onResume");
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Message(this.user, this.event)),
      );
    }, onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> msg) {
      print("onMessage");
    });
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, alert: true, badge: true));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings setting) {
      print("IOS");
    });

//sendTokenToServer() - function send FCM token my Postgres DB

//When user clicks on send Button

Future sendNotification(userData, eventData) async {
    await Messaging.sendToAll(
      title:
          "${toBeginningOfSentenceCase(userData['User']['name'])} on ${toBeginningOfSentenceCase(eventData['Event']['eventName'])} event",
      body: _messageController.text,
      fcmToken: fcmTokenToServer,
    );
  }

//Messaging.sendToAll()
static Future<Response> sendToAll(
          {@required String title,
          @required String body,
          @required String fcmToken}) =>
      sendTo(title: title, body: body, fcmToken: fcmToken);

  static Future<Response> sendTo({
    @required String title,
    @required String body,
    @required String fcmToken,
  }) =>
      client.post(
        'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send',
        body: json.encode({
          'notification': {'body': '$body', 'title': '$title'},
          'priority': 'high',
          'data': {
            'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
            'id': '1',
            'status': 'done',
          },
          'to': '$fcmToken',
        }),
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'key=$serverKey',
        },
      );
```

But No push notification is receiving. Is it that I have to implement cloud functions to send notification??

Comment: I could send the notifications from one device to other using FCM token as well as using the Topic id. The code is also same. Please try with the topic as well may be the token is wrong

Comment: @shyju-madathil have you used firestore to device store token or your db on server??

Comment: No server...one device to another device. In my app, to send comment notifications to the post owner

Comment: Did you solve it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I could send FCM messages from one device to other with the topic/FCM token without the server.

NOTE : Using the server key at client side is a bad practice and should not be used in production-level applications.

```java
static Future<bool> sendFcmMessage(String title, String message) async {
    try {
      
      var url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
      var header = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization":
            "key=your_server_key",
      };
      var request = {
        "notification": {
          "title": title,
          "text": message,
          "sound": "default",
          "color": "#990000",
        },
        "priority": "high",
        "to": "/topics/all",
      };

      var client = new Client();
      var response =
          await client.post(url, headers: header, body: json.encode(request));
      return true;
    } catch (e, s) {
      print(e);
      return false;
    }
}
```

If you have to send data request with FCM token, use

```
request = {
      'notification': {'title': title, 'body': message},
      'data': {
        'click_action': 'FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK',
        'type': 'COMMENT'
      },
      'to': 'fcmtoken'
    };
```

Comment: How can add this to topic `/topics/user-{userId}` which will send to particular device?

Comment: You can send with the fcmtoken only, cannot use topic with userid

Comment: *firebaser here* Using `"key=your_server_key"` in client-side code is a serious security risk, as it allows malicious users to send whatever message they want to your users. This is a bad practice and should not be used in production-level applications. For a better approach, see https://fireship.io/lessons/flutter-push-notifications-fcm-guide/ and my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57842615